# correspondence between locally free sheaf of finite rank equipped with flat connection and the local system

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry

The $(X,C^\infty)$ is a smooth manifold then we have the following theorem which says

> the category of locally free sheaves of finite rank with flat
> connection is equivalent to the category of $\Bbb{R}$-local system.

The functor between the category of locally free sheaves with flat connection and the category of the local system as shown in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236993/360262), takes the kernel of the connection and gives $\mathcal{L} = \ker \nabla$.

---

**I try to prove that $\mathcal{L}$ is a local system.**

In the language of a vector bundle, the kernel of the connection is some parallel section of bundle, if the connection is flat we can parallel transport along the coordinate axis, since the commutation relation $$[\nabla_{\partial_i},\nabla_{\partial_j}] = 0$$
we can prove that this process really produces a section such that $\nabla s = 0$ that independent order of translation. (See for example Lee's Riemannian manifold book Lemma 7.8).

However, I don't know how to prove it is a local system after that. (That is I want to show  $\mathcal{L}|_U \cong \underline{\Bbb{R}}^k$ )

Comment: Why locally free sheaf needs not to be local system, for example the vector bundle is locally trivial and therefore has the form $U\times \Bbb{R}^r$ while $U$ as open subset of base manifold also isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^n$ therefore the local free sheaf isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{n+r}$ also, therefore also local system?

Comment: To answer your comment above: I think you've misunderstood a lot of parts of the definition. A locally free local system of $\mathbb{R}$-spaces locally looks like $\underline{\mathbb{R}}^n$ (this is a **constant** sheaf), a vector bundle locally looks like $(C^\infty_X)^n$ (not a constant sheaf). If you want to compare a local system's etale space to the vector bundle, the difference is that locally one looks like $U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ where the $\mathbb{R}^n$-facotr has the **discrete** topology, and the other like $U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ where now $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the usual topology.

Comment: thank you Alex Youcis , that solves my problem in the comment(and I will work out the etale space later). I misunderstood the fact that sheaf correspond to the vector bundle is sheaf of section(which is locally free), although vector bundle is locally euclidean, the associated sheaf is not locally constant sheaf

Comment: For the Etale space, the sheaf of section of vector bundle is already a sheaf, the Etale space isomorphic to the vector bundle it self, therefore the topology on $U\times \Bbb{R}^n$ is the standard one on the vector bundle.  For the constant sheaf, the Etale space has the topology that all the rough section on $\text{Et}(\underline{\Bbb{R}^n}) \to U$ is continuous, therefore it has to have discrete topology by the definition