# understanding the kernel of the connection $\ker \nabla$ on $E$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was trying to understand the kernel of the connection on a smooth vevtor bundle $E$.

Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle, we can associate a connection on $E$, which defines $$\nabla:\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(T^*_{M}\otimes E)$$ that satisfies the Leibniz rule.

Is $\ker \nabla \subset E$ sub vector bundle of $E$? why it's a distribution on $E$?

Comment: There are several issues here. A connection isn't a pointwise operator on the bundle; it's an operator on sections of the bundle. You certainly cannot assign $\nabla e$ for a fixed element $e$ of $E$. And then there's a question of what a distribution on $E$ should be; shouldn't that be a subbundle of $TE$?

Comment: Thank you @Ted Shifrin , I realized that I made a mistake on the definition of connection above, It should be a sheaf homomorphism of sheaf of section. Distribution on $E$ is subbundle of $TE$, I saw another post says that $\ker \nabla$ is distribution on $E$ , https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3237166/360262 . However I found in standard textbook that the vertical and horizental part of $E\to M$ should be defined using the differential of $d\pi: TE \to TM$ not the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E \rightarrow M$ a smooth vector bundle on a manifold $M$. Let $\Gamma(E)$ be the space of sections. A connection on $E$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map

$$
\nabla : \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma\left(E \otimes T^{*} M\right)
$$
satisfyng Leibniz rule
$$
\nabla(f \sigma )=\sigma \otimes d f+f \cdot \nabla \sigma
$$

This way, if $X$ is a vector field one can define a notion of derivative of a section
$$
\nabla_{X} : \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)
$$
by means of $\nabla_{X} \sigma=(\nabla \sigma)(X)$.

If we think of sections like a generalization of functions (I personally call them twisted functions) the connection is a device that let us derive this functions.

This concept is nothing but a particular case of a [connection on a fiber bundle](https://personalnotes.000webhostapp.com/desktop/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/GEOMETRY/connection%20on%20a%20fiber%20bundle.md.html) when the bundle is a vector bundle.
I think that **what you are looking for is** that every derivative operator gives rise to **horizontal subspaces** in $TE$.

For every $e\in E$, with $\pi(e)=x\in M$, we have a "natural" linear space $T_e E_x$ that is called the *vertical space*. The union in $e\in E$ gives us a subbundle $V\subseteq TE$ called the *vertical bundle*.
At a first glance, there is no natural choice for an *horizontal bundle*, but $\nabla$ determines one. We will define
$$
H_e:=ds_x (T_x M)
$$
where $s$ is a section such that $s(x)=e$ and $\nabla_X s=0$ for every $X\in T_x M$.

This way, the vector bundle connection determines an [Ehresmann connection](https://personalnotes.000webhostapp.com/desktop/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/GEOMETRY/connection%20on%20a%20fiber%20bundle.md.html).

I have written more [ideas on vector bundle connections here](https://personalnotes.000webhostapp.com/desktop/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/GEOMETRY/vector%20bundle%20connection.md.html).

**Edited**

Maybe, what you are looking for is what follows.In a general setup (not necessarily a vector bundle) a way to specify a connection consists of a projection, i.e., a map $v:TE\mapsto TE$ such that $v^2=v$, and with $v(T_e E)=V_e$. In this case, $H_e=ker(v|_{T_e E})$. Remember that in any vector space $W$, a map such tat $p^2=p$ lets you decompose $W=ker(p)\oplus im(p)$ (see [projection](https://personalnotes.000webhostapp.com/desktop/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/projection.md.html)). The idea behind is that you can comprise $W$ to $p(W)$ in so many ways as horizontal subspaces choices.
So equivalently, the horizontal subbundle can be described by a $TE$-valued 1-form on $E$, called **the connection form**.

**One more interpretation of your doubt**

On the other hand, I guess you could define $(\ker \nabla)_e$ as a vector  subspace of $T_e E$ which is tangent at $e\in E$ to the image of any section $s:M\to E$ which is horizontal in $e$, i.e., such that $\nabla_X s=0$ for every $X\in T_{\pi(e)}X$.

Comment: Thank you, I still can't see why $\nabla $ choose horizental part as its kernel?

Comment: I have added a little to the answer

Comment: I have added one more point to the answer. I hope now is clear

Comment: Thank you Antonio J Pan. There has some gaps that I need to fill in.